# How to create a PopupWindow with images?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to create a popup window similar to programmatically. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out any helpful resource so far for creating a similar popup.

[image: PopupWindow from Android Design Guidelines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.chat_custom_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("custom dialog");
    dialog.show();
```

where `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.chat_custom_dialog);` will set the layout of the dialog.

And if you want to update the dialog's layout views you can call the `dialog.findViewById(id)` to get the view inside of the layout same as what you are doing in the activity